# Preg_match with referenced variable in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

The following code does not give me the expected results.

```
if (isset($newpost['message']))
{
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all("~\[QUOTE\=.*;(\d+)\]~isU", $newpost['message'], $matches);

    var_dump($matches);
    die();
}
```

$matches should contain the matched results.
However, $matches always is equal to the whole $newpost array (not only the message part).
The result of the above could look like this:

```
array(22) { ["message"]=> string(17) "testing123..." ["title"]=> &string(0) "" ["iconid"]=> &int(0) ["parseurl"]=> bool(true) ["signature"]=> &int(1) ["preview"]=> &string(0) "" ["disablesmilies"]=> &int(0) ["rating"]=> &int(0) ["username"]=> &string(0) "" ["folderid"]=> &int(0) ["quickreply"]=> &int(0) ["poststarttime"]=> &int(1368357609) ["posthash"]=> &string(32) "4d513f4123f780c6b10739e3a5dd0fb6" ["humanverify"]=> &array(0) { } ["stickunstick"]=> &int(0) ["openclose"]=> &int(0) ["ajaxqrfailed"]=> int(0) ["emailupdate"]=> &int(9999) ["enablesmilies"]=> int(1) ["podcastsize"]=> int(0) ["visible"]=> int(1) ["postid"]=> int(1771567) }
```

I think this is because $newpost might be handled as a reference. Not sure, though...

Comment: By the way, `$matches = array();` This statement is unneeded. When undefined variable passed by reference, PHP automatically initialize it as NULL without any errors.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing, but I would think that this code is never executed and the output is from something else, also you don't have to specify `$matches = array();` (you can just remove it)

Comment: Initializing the match variable is a safety measure. There could be other match variables in the script.

Comment: But you were right. I have confirmed that the output must come from somewhere else...

Comment: @reggie No. It is initialized every preg_match_all call, so you don't have to do it by yourself. See this: http://ideone.com/a09LoS Offset "first" is removed after second call.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this code on Ideone and it worked expectedly.

Code:

```
<?php

$text = <<<EOD
abc [QUOTE=ABC;123]
def [Quote=DEF;456]
ghi
EOD;

$newpost = array('message' => $text);

if (isset($newpost['message'])) {
    preg_match_all('/\\[QUOTE=[^;]++;(\\d++)\\]/i', $newpost['message'], $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "[QUOTE=ABC;123]"
    [1]=>
    string(15) "[Quote=DEF;456]"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "123"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "456"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Output came from somewhere else in the script...